# How can I change a GPT unique partition GUID on windows?

Tags: windows, partitioning, gpt

According to the GPT section found in chapter 5 of the UEFI specification version 3.6.0, every GPT partition entry has a unique GUID at byte offset 16. My question can kind of be broken up into 2 parts:

1. Does Windows provide any facilities for safely modifying unique partition GUIDs?
2. Assuming the answer to question 1 is no, what must I take into consideration when doing it manually? Can I do it safely by writing to \\.\PhysicalDriveX from kernel land while the system is running? What about using an EFI driver at boot time?

PS: There is no other way to achieve my goals so there is no need to leave a good natured but ultimately useless comment asking me why I want to do this or if I have considered alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Beware: If a partition’s UUID is changed, and that partition is involved in the boot process, the BCD must be altered accordingly, because partitions are specified in the BCD by these UUIDs.

Also, drive letters are assigned to UUIDs in Windows’ Registry in HKLM\System\Mounted Devices.

Partition Editor software can change the UUIDs at will, this will not affect a running Windows, but might—as mentioned above—affect bootability and drive letters.

Simply changing the UUID at offset 16 with hex editor won’t work, as I’m sure you’re aware, since the validity of the GPT is protected by a checksum, so you’d have to recalculate that, too (and you’d have to do it on the primary and secondary/backup GPT). Or simply use a partition editor that can do that for you.

And because the Partition table is outside of any volume, writing to it (i.e. \PhysicalDriveX) will work, as long as you have administrative rights, without having to get any lock to the drive.

Comment: Thanks! Can you recommend a partition software (GUI or command line) that isn't just shitty bloatware like 90% of windows utilities?

Comment: sorry, I’m not on Windows, and have no experience with what tools are available there. I know of the GPT/UUID/Boot/Drive Letter issue through my daytime job (where we use proprietary software for doing so).

Comment: @RealName Software recommendations are off -topic on [su]

Comment: @Ro-ee Okay, using your answer I wrote a custom utility that successfully modified the GUIDs in the GPT header and all the partition headers. I didn’t heed your warning about the boot thing and now my PC won’t boot. It looks like I will have to edit the bcd variables after booting from install media. Which one do I have to update in particular to get my pc to boot again? Thanks.

Comment: I’d recommend using bcdboot to connect the boot and windows partitions to their new UUIDs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-8.1-and-8/hh824874(v=win.10)

Comment: I totally reset the BCD using bootrec /rebuildbcd and it still bluescreens with INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE. There must be some registry value at play here. Any idea where it might be?

Answer (score 1):

The post
[How do I manually change the Partition Type GUID](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593761/how-do-i-manually-change-the-partition-type-guid)
has this answer by fpmurphy:

> Windows `DiskPart` can easily do that.  Select the appropriate disk
> and partition, then use the `set id` subcommand.
>
> `set id=7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`
>
> Reference and documentation:
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set-id

Comment: OP is not referring to the type, but the unique partition ID. It's different for every partition, even if they are of the same type.